# How can I read logs from a AWS SQS queue into FluentD?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-sqs, fluentd

I'm trying to read some logs in my AWS SQS queue into fluentd. I thought the `fluent-plugin-s3` plugin takes care of this but after reading the documentation it seems that it only writes to an S3 bucket.

`s3 output plugin buffers event logs in local file and upload it to S3 periodically.`

I'm using the [VMWare's Fluentd operator](https://github.com/vmware/kube-fluentd-operator) and it only comes with a default list of plugins.

My question is, is there a way I can use any of the default curated plugins to read incoming logs from AWS SQS into Fluentd? If the default plugin's aren't suitable, how can I install a plugin for this Fluentd operator? for eg. [fluent-plugin-s3-input](https://github.com/ansoni/fluent-plugin-s3-input)

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SQS has a dedicated plugin for input: https://github.com/ixixi/fluent-plugin-sqs

I've found it here: https://www.fluentd.org/plugins

S3 plugin uses SQS just to track S3 events like newly created files and read them.